# Css fixed display not working in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to duplicate the getsatisfaction tab kind of effect - it works fine in IE7 and Firefox and almost every other browser but its all messed up in Explorer 6 - I hate IE6 but heck its the most commonly used browser - my tab is now instead of being overlayed on the side is sitting at the top corner of my page pushing all the page contents to the bottom.

The tab is just a link with this css styling applied:

```
a#feedback_link
{
  position:fixed; top:40%; 
  right:0px !important; 
  z-index:9999999; 
  text-decoration:none; 
  background-color:#2E8CDC; 
  padding:0px; 
  border:0px;
}
```

Comment: It's technically not correct that IE6 is "the most commonly used browser".  See http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2 ... Today, IE7 is top at ~41% and IE6 at ~17%.  (Though I agree ~17% is still significant.)

Comment: Hmmm - didn't know bout that - the less people use IE6 the better - anyway Thanks to EVERYONE for the great helpful hints :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, before I start: IE6 is actually the most THINK TO BE commonly used browser. [Let the numbers talk](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp).

The issue is probably with the "fixed" positioning.
change it to absolute (and change the code if needed) or use conditional css to make a special css for ie6 only.

see some samples here: http://snipplr.com/view/2952/ie6-fixed-position-fix/

Comment: Not the best page to be linking to when arguing browser usage numbers... as they say themselves at the bottom: "W3Schools is a website for people with an interest for web technologies. These people are more interested in using alternative browsers than the average user. The average user tends to use Internet Explorer, since it comes preinstalled with Windows. Most do not seek out other browsers. These facts indicate that the browser figures above are not 100% realistic. Other web sites have statistics showing that Internet Explorer is used by at least 80% of the users."

Answer (score 2):

`display: fixed` is not supported in IE6

see: http://tagsoup.com/cookbook/css/fixed/ for some workarounds to this problem

Answer (score 2):

IE6 ignores position:fixed. It's a known defect. One possible (but somewhat ugly) workaround is to use JavaScript expressions in your CSS file like so:

```
a#feedback_link
{
    position:absolute; 
    top:expression(eval(document.documentElement.scrollTop+document.documentElement.clientHeight*0.4));
    ...
```

Use conditional comments to limit this declaration to IE6 only.

Comment: if you do so, it is important that such css rules be nested in IE conditional comments

Answer (score 2):

`display: fixed` is not supported in IE6.

If you want to make it work, I suggest trying [IE7.js or IE8.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), which are a compatibility patch (implemented through JavaScript) for IE6 that enables support for `display: fixed`.

You can see an overview of what `IE7.js` does here:

[`http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/ie7_script.html`](http://www.charlescooke.me.uk/web/lab_notes/ie7_script.html)